# How to output hash table query result into Out-GridView?

Tags: azure, powershell

I wish to export a hashtable result into Out-GridView using the Powershell.

The purpose of the below script is to export the **Azure VM tags to Out-GridView**, it throws error like the below blank result:

[image]

Error on the console:

```
Out-GridView : Syntax error in PropertyPath 'Syntax error in Binding.Path '[ Product] ' ... '(Tag)'.'.
At line:46 char:19
+         $Output | Out-GridView #Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\1a.csv -appe ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Out-GridView], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ManagementListInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutGridViewCommand
```

This is the actual script which was executed under the Global Administrator role:

```
<#
.AUTHOR: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13390556/lukasz-g
#>
$Subscription = Get-AzSubscription | Out-GridView -Title 'Select subscription' -OutputMode 'Multiple'

# Initialise output array
$Output = @()

if ($Subscription) {
    foreach ($item in $Subscription) {
        $item | Select-AzSubscription

        # Collect all the resources or resource groups (comment one of below)
        $Resource = Get-AzResource
        #$Resource = Get-AzResourceGroup

        # Obtain a unique list of tags for these groups collectively
        $UniqueTags = $Resource.Tags.GetEnumerator().Keys | Get-Unique -AsString | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique | Where-Object { $_ -notlike "hidden-*" }

        # Loop through the resource groups
        foreach ($ResourceGroup in $Resource) {
            # Create a new ordered hashtable and add the normal properties first.
            $RGHashtable = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
            $RGHashtable.Add("Name", $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName)
            $RGHashtable.Add("Location", $ResourceGroup.Location)
            $RGHashtable.Add("Id", $ResourceGroup.ResourceId)
            $RGHashtable.Add("ResourceType", $ResourceGroup.ResourceType)

            # Loop through possible tags adding the property if there is one, adding it with a hyphen as it's value if it doesn't.
            if ($ResourceGroup.Tags.Count -ne 0) {
                $UniqueTags | Foreach-Object {
                    if ($ResourceGroup.Tags[$_]) {
                        $RGHashtable.Add("[$_] (Tag)", $ResourceGroup.Tags[$_])
                    }
                    else {
                        $RGHashtable.Add("[$_] (Tag)", "-")
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $UniqueTags | Foreach-Object { $RGHashtable.Add("[$_] (Tag)", "-") }
            }

            # Update the output array, adding the ordered hashtable we have created for the ResourceGroup details.
            $Output += New-Object psobject -Property $RGHashtable
        }

        # Sent the final output to CSV
        $Output | Out-GridView #Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\1a.csv -append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$RGHashtable.Add("[$_] (Tag)"
```

In above code,  You are trying to add something like below :

In the output

[image]

Removed everthing and I tested with  simple statements

```
$Output = @()
$RGHashtable = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
$RGHashtable.Add("[Testing] (Name)", "Temporary")
$Output += New-Object psobject -Property $RGHashtable
$Output | Out-GridView
```

I was provided with the same error.

[image]

After couple of testing,  understood the error only occurs when there is a combination "`[SomeString](SomeString)`"  --- `[...](....)` in the string.

The Out-GridView is trying to parse the "`[<SomeString>](<SomeString>)`" and hence the error.

You could try any 1 of the below combination in your code :

```
$RGHashtable.Add("[$_] [Tag]", $ResourceGroup.Tags[$_])
```

OR

```
$RGHashtable.Add("{$_} (Tag)", $ResourceGroup.Tags[$_])
```

OR

```
$RGHashtable.Add("[$_] [Tag]", $ResourceGroup.Tags[$_])
```

This should resolve your issue.

you will have change in 3 instances in your code if I am not wrong.

Comment: @seniorSystemsEngineer - Please consider marking it as solution if it had helped.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have any queries pls let me know.